# How to fix "TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'" on dynamic object

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have a code like below:

```js
interface Schema$CommonEventObject {
        formInputs?: {
            [key: string]: Schema$Inputs;
        } | null;
     }
interface Schema$Inputs {
        stringInputs?: Schema$StringInputs;
    }
interface Schema$StringInputs {
        value?: string[] | null;
    }
const commonEvent: Schema$CommonEventObject = event?.common ?? {};
const formValues = commonEvent.formInputs ?? {};
const topic = formValues?.['topic']?.stringInputs?.value[0];
const isAnonymous = formValues?.['is_anonymous']?.stringInputs.value[0] === '1';
```

it return error:

> TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
>
> TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'

BTW, i'm using `Schema$CommonEventObject` from [googleapis chat library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/086eb9a88e80400e8e6476e821098c946228270c/src/apis/chat/v1.ts#L381):

how to fix these TS errors? Actually it working fine if I set `strictNullChecks=false`. But I want to set it as true to follow best practice.

I tried using null coalescing operator like below

```
  const topic = formValues?.['topic']?.stringInputs?.value[0] ?? '';
```

and still return the same error.

I also tried to use non-null assertion operator like below:

```
  const topic = formValues!.['topic']!.stringInputs!.value[0];
```

and return another error:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"topic"' can't be used to index type 'Schema$Inputs'.   Property 'topic' does not exist on type 'Schema$Inputs'.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing, without unrelated errors like missing type/value definitions.  Also make sure your tags are accurate; you are almost certainly not using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Comment: @jcalz it my bad for using that tag, I removed it. and I believe my codes is reproducible. And now I merged the interface and code, so it can be done using copy paste in one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to `stringInputs?.value`.
So, the correct code is

```
const topic = formValues?.['topic']?.stringInputs?.value?.[0];
```

but above still can return `undefined`, so I can add [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) like below

```
const topic = formValues?.['topic']?.stringInputs?.value?.[0] ?? '';
```